# Efficiently take moving average of sparse data and filter above threshold in python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, sparse-matrix, moving-average

I am getting my feet wet with some genome analysis and am a little stuck. I have some very sparse data and need to find places where the moving average exceeds some threshold, marking each point as 1 or 0. The data is of a unique type, so I can't use available programs for analysis.

Each point represents one point (basepair) on the human genome. For each dataset there are 200,000,000 potential points. The data is essentially a list of ~12000 index/value pairs where all other points are assumed to be zero. What I need to do is take a moving average across the whole dataset, and return regions where the average is above a threshold.

I am currently reading each point from the dataset sequentially and building an array around each point that I find, but this is very slow for large window sizes. Is there a more efficient way to do this, maybe with scipy or pandas?

Edit: Jamie's magic code below works great (but I can't upvote yet)! I am extremely appreciative.

Comment: Maybe it would make more sense to convert the data into a format that is understood by available programs. Data conversion is most likely far easier to implement than complex analysis and result visualization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can vectorize the whole thing with numpy. I have built this random dataset of (approx.) 12,000 indices between 0 and 199,999,999, and an equally long list of random floats between 0 and 1:

```
indices = np.unique(np.random.randint(2e8,size=(12000,)))
values = np.random.rand(len(indices))
```

Then  I construct an array of indices of total window size `2*win+1` around each of the `indices`, and a corresponding array of how much is contributed to the moving average by that point:

```
win = 10

avg_idx = np.arange(-win, win+1) + indices[:, None]
avg_val = np.tile(values[:, None]/(2*win+1), (1, 2*win+1))
```

All that is left is figuring out repeated indices and adding contributions to the moving average together:

```
unique_idx, _ = np.unique(avg_idx, return_inverse=True)
mov_avg = np.bincount(_, weights=avg_val.ravel())
```

You can now get the list of indices at which, e.g. the moving average exceeds 0.5, as:

```
unique_idx[mov_avg > 0.5]
```

As for performance, first turn the above code into a function:

```
def sparse_mov_avg(idx, val, win):
    avg_idx = np.arange(-win, win+1) + idx[:, None]
    avg_val = np.tile(val[:, None]/(2*win+1), (1, 2*win+1))
    unique_idx, _ = np.unique(avg_idx, return_inverse=True)
    mov_avg = np.bincount(_, weights=avg_val.ravel())
    return unique_idx, mov_avg
```

and here are some timings for several window sizes, for the test data described at the beginning:

```
In [2]: %timeit sparse_mov_avg(indices, values, 10)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.7 ms per loop

In [3]: %timeit sparse_mov_avg(indices, values, 100)
1 loops, best of 3: 378 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit sparse_mov_avg(indices, values, 1000)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.33 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to really think about the question. Most of the code is foreign to me because I haven't used numpy much, so this is very helpful. I feel like I wasted so much time working on this when you came up with a superior solution so quickly!

Comment: I'm finding that increasing the window size to greater than about 100 results in a memory error :(

Comment: @MarkB That doesn't make much sense. With the numbers you provided the moving average would only be an array of a few million entries.

Comment: I checked out my data sets in greater detail, and some had up to 150,000 records in them. With your sample data, I got a memoryError when window size increased to 2000, so that makes sense (10x more data, 10x smaller window size). It looks like even though I have 8Gb memory on this machine, python can't use more than 1Gb of it. However, your code still was very useful. What I ended up doing was setting a chunk_size parameter, then iterating through the data using your algorithm with [chunk_begin-win]:[chunk_end+win], then stitching together the chunks.